# Karate: ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - not a valid feature file: mismatched input 'S' expecting <EOF>

Tags: karate

I am trying to automate a SOAP service using Karate 1.1.0 and when I run the test, I am getting the below error

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - not a valid feature file: features/syncSupplier/syncSupplier.feature - mismatched input 'S' expecting <EOF>
```

**Feature file**

```
@SyncSupplierFeature

Feature: SyncSupplier service

  Background:
    * url 'https://qaintservices.abc.com:4445/int/services/SyncSupplierService/1.4'
    * configure ssl = true

  Scenario : Send valid Supplier message to the service
    * def syncSupplierRequest = read('syncSupplierRequest.xml')
    Given request syncSupplierRequest
    When soap action '/services/SupplierService'
    Then status 200
```

**Testrunner**

```
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

class TestRunner {  @Karate.Test
    Karate testSyncSupplier() {
        return Karate.run("features/syncSupplier/syncSupplier").relativeTo(getClass());
    } }
```

I am not sure if it is because of https://.  I have automated other rest services and those are working fine but they all have http://. Should I do anything differently for an https call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between `Scenario` and the `:` please:

```
Scenario:
```